# Windows service not working because of Error 1064

Tags: c#, windows-services

I wrote a Windows service and when I want to run this service, I get an error "Error 1064: An exception occurred in the service when handling the control reques".

I want the service I'm writing to monitor the event viewer and capture an event and take action on it.

OnStart

```
      protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            this.ServiceName = "Wumed";
            Console.WriteLine("Service başlatıldı");
            EventLogSubscription();
        }
```

OnStop

```
 protected override void OnStop()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Service durduruldu");
            _watcher?.Dispose();
            base.OnStop();
        }
```

Main

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var service = new wumed())
            {
                service.ServiceName = "Wumed";
                if (Environment.UserInteractive)
                {
                    service.OnStart(args);
                    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop the service.");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    service.OnStop();
                }
                else
                {
                    ServiceBase.Run(service);
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried running everything as administrator. When I compiled the code, I did not encounter any errors.

Comment: Does the code work when you (a) run as the same user as the service does and (b) from the console (since you use `UserInteractive`)? Also, check the Windows EventLog ("Applications" Log) for errors of your own service.

Comment: It shows 3 errors in Event Viewer. This is also the description of "The service cannot be started. System.InvalidOperationException: The name cannot be changed while the service is running."

Comment: No guarantees, but in general it helps if you post full stack traces / error messages in your question. You can edit it and update it accordingly.